# Getting full size image from thumbnail using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, search

I have a thumbnail like so:

https://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRqiTFaM7y1YzsA9iKy7a5hZsqsQcdsvAXYhPNUnWZdt-Qk6l-OkaRQdpgDKYnrAJIO8ieRf8RJ

and I want to get the full sized image from the thumbnail.

The only thing that has come up so far is to do a reverse google image search of the thumbnail.

My current plan is to use this:

```
https://github.com/vivithemage/mrisa
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you allowed to [resize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=resize#PIL.Image.Image.resize) the image?

Comment: I didn't think of that because I thought the image quality will be affected @BalajiAmbresh

Comment: The thumbnail.. @MarkSetchell

Comment: If all you have is a URL, you don't have any way of knowing if a full sized image exists anywhere. Maybe for some specific sites there could be a predictable way to get at larger images (if what you have genuinely is a thumbnail), but there's no way to do it for an arbitrary image.

Comment: TinEye finds the full-size image https://images2.gazzettaobjects.it/methode_image/2020/05/02/Calcio/Foto_Calcio_-_Trattate/6a5af73a369a645e221e3a18607cc3e7_620x349.jpg?v=20200502163342